# How to get full tweet text in retweets (not using tweepy!)?

Tags: python, twitter

I have a few ndjson files containing twitter data. I ran into the problem, that for retweets the "text" property of the dictionaries only includes the first 140 characters. I would like to extract the full tweet.

By taking one of the tweets and running the following code:

```
data.get('includes')['tweets']
```

I get the following result.

```
[{'attachments': {'media_keys': [‘’1234”]},
  'author_id': “1234”,
  'conversation_id': “1234”,
  'created_at': '2021-02-10T14:27:19.000Z',
  'entities': {'annotations': [{'end': 111,
     'normalized_text': 'Scotland',
     'probability': 0.9519,
     'start': 104,
     'type': 'Place'}],
   'hashtags': [{'end': 50, 'start': 35, 'tag': 'ChineseNewYear'}],
   'urls': [{'display_url': 'pic.twitter.com/1234’,
     'end': 221,
     'expanded_url': ‘urlwuhuu,
     'start': 198,
     'url': “another one”}]},
  'id': “1234”,
  'lang': 'en',
  'possibly_sensitive': False,
  'public_metrics': {'like_count': 7,
   'quote_count': 0,
   'reply_count': 6,
   'retweet_count': 3},
  'reply_settings': 'everyone',
  'source': 'Twitter Web App',
  'text': “FULL TWEET THAT I WANT TO GET”}]
```

The problem is that what I have now is a list and not a dictionary. To get the tweet (at the end of the list) I cannot use the .get function or index using string.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [list comprehension](https://pythongeeks.org/list-comprehensions-in-python/), for example:

```
tweets_list = data.get('includes')['tweets']
tweet_texts  = [ tweet['text'] for tweet in tweets_list ] # gets the texts of all tweets, as a list
text = tweet_texts[0] # get “FULL TWEET THAT I WANT TO GET” from your example
```